# Debug script without XDEBUG_SESSION_START parameter

Tags: php, xdebug

I am debugging a web service in PHP and there is no facility for adding the XDEBUG_SESSION_START to the single buggy remote server that has issues that don't happen in my test servers. I do know ahead of time before the server in question makes its GET request to the web service. **Is there any way to have Xdebug run for the next request, even if the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` parameter is not sent?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to add `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` to `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and restart Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.